# Does the .NET 6 Preview SDK installer for MacOS remove my previous .NET 5 SDK packages?

Tags: .net, macos

I just installed the .Net 6 preview on MacOS. I'd like this to fully replace anything .NET 5 related.

When I run `dotnet --version` it shows version 6 but where can I go to check if version 5 is still installed? I'd like to delete it.

This is on MacOS 12.0 Beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't; .NET Core was designed so that you can have multiple versions installed at once.

You can check the installed SDKs with `dotnet --list-sdks`, the runtimes with `dotnet --list-runtimes` or `dotnet --info` for both.

To delete a specific version of the runtime, you can run:

```sh
version="5.0.0"
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/$version
```

Cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-macos and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions